# Dynamic URL -> Controller mapping for routes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller, url-routing

I would like to be able to map URLs to Controllers dynamically based on information in my database.

I'm looking to do something functionally equivalent to this (assuming a `View` model):

```
map.route '/:view_name',
    :controller => lambda { View.find_by_name(params[:view_name]).controller }
```

Others have suggested [dynamically rebuilding the routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/776268/dynamic-cms-like-routes-in-ruby-on-rails/806516#806516), but this won't work for me as there **may be thousands of Views that map to the same Controller**

Comment: The controller need not be determined by a database record, I just want some way to evaluate which controller to use for a given route at Runtime, instead of Designtime.

Comment: Still never found a solution to this, though it seems like a simple task.  Maybe a Rack-Application that re-writes URLs?

Answer (score 13):

This question is old, but I found it interesting. A fully working solution can be created in Rails 3 using  router's capability to route to a Rack endpoint.

Create the following Rack class:

```
    class MyRouter
      def call(env)
        # Matched from routes, you can access all matched parameters
        view_name= env['action_dispatch.request.path_parameters'][:view_name]

        # Compute these the way you like, possibly using view_name
        controller= 'post' 
        my_action= 'show'

        controller_class= (controller + '_controller').camelize.constantize
        controller_class.action(my_action.to_sym).call(env)
      end
    end
```

In Routes

```
    match '/:view_name', :to => MyRouter.new, :via => :get
```

Hint picked up from http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#routing-to-rack-applications which says "For the curious, 'posts#index' actually expands out to PostsController.action(:index), which returns a valid Rack application."

A variant tested in Rails 3.2.13.

Answer (score 0):

So I think that you are asking that if you have a Views table and a View model for it where the table looks like

```
id | name | model
===================
1  | aaa  | Post
2  | bbb  | Post
3  | ccc  | Comment
```

You want a url of /aaa to point to Post.controller - is this right?

If not then what you suggest seems fine assuming it works.

You could send it to a catch all action and have the action look at the url, run the find_by_name and then call the correct controller from there.

```
def catch_all
  View.find_by_name('aaa').controller.action
end
```

## Update

You can use redirect_to and even send the params. In the example below you I am sending the search parameters

```
def catch_all
  new_controller = View.find_by_name('aaa').controller
  redirect_to :controller => new_controller, :action => :index, 
      :search => params[:search] 
end
```

Comment: How do you "call the correct controller"?  Rails maintains instances of each controller and sets up Requests contexts, populates `params`, and lots of other stuff, how do I instruct rails to forward the request from within one controller to another one?

Comment: redirect_to will send a [302 HTTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_302) response to the client, causing the browser to re-request the new URL.  This isn't what we want.

Comment: You used to be able to use render_component in pre rails 2.3 but if you still want to do that then checkout the http://github.com/rails/render_component plugin

Comment: "redirect_to" doesn't look like an answer for the question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a nice Rack Routing solution to SEO contributed by zetetic and Steve ross

[Testing Rack Routing Using rSpec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641786/testing-rack-routing-using-rspec)

It shows you how to write a custom dispatcher (where you can do a db lookup if needed) and with constraints, and testing as well.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the question [Rails routing to handle multiple domains on single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207657/rails-routing-to-handle-multiple-domains-on-single-application), I guess you could use [Rails Routing - Advanced Constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints) to build what you need.

If you have a limited space of controllers (with unlimited views pointing to them), this should work. Just create a constraint for each controller that verifies if the current view matches them.

Assuming you have a space of 2 controllers (PostController and CommentController), you could add the following to your routes.rb:

```
match "*path" => "post#show", :constraints => PostConstraint.new
match "*path" => "comment#show", :constraints => CommentConstraint.new
```

Then, create lib/post_constraint.rb:

```
class PostConstraint     
  def matches?(request)
    'post' == Rails.cache.fetch("/view_controller_map/#{request.params[:view_name]}") { View.find_by_name(request.params[:view_name]).controller }
  end
end
```

Finally, create lib/comment_constraint.rb:

```
class CommentConstraint     
  def matches?(request)
    'comment' == Rails.cache.fetch("/view_controller_map/#{request.params[:view_name]}") { View.find_by_name(request.params[:view_name]).controller }
  end
end
```

You can do some improvements, like defining a super constraint class that fetches the cache, so you don't have to repeat code and don't risk fetching a wrong cache key name in one of the constraints.