# show one application on 2 site with different front ends but same back end, in ROR hosted on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

I have an application in rails and hosted on Heroku. Now , what I want is that the application can be accessed from 2 different domains, when the application is accessed from suppose a.com it should have a specific frontend, and when accessed from b.com it should display some other frontend. The backend should be same for both. 
To achieve this I suppose there is only one way I guess, which is to have two different application with same backed code, and same database(I am using PostgreSQL). I need some help on how Do I achieve this, if not, then some other alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have only one app for both if it's easier for you. I would then suggest you configure config/routes.rb to respond differently according to the domain name.

See another answer about it here: [Rails routing to handle multiple domains on single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207657/rails-routing-to-handle-multiple-domains-on-single-application)

And the Advanced Contraints in Rails here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints

Comment: Not too familiar with Heroku but I guess what you're saying is that Heroku sets up your DNS for you? And in no way you could point two records to the same IP? That'd be weird. Imagine pointing different alias of your domain to the same app.. Heroku wouldn't allow that??

Comment: they have provision for one domain to be added through their interface.

Comment: I doubt that'd be through. Indeed I found this: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains. You'll be just fine :)

Comment: through... true. Ouch. That was bad. Grammar Nazi would have ripped me off.