# Rails App inside a Rails app's sub-folder

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app, but a client wants to have another rails app be hosted in a ssub-folder of the first rails app.

I can't find any help on how to do this or if it's possible, because if I go to:

http://example.com/second_app, the first app will try and route it despite another app being situated in the second_app folder.

I hope this makes sense, and someone will be able to help.

Comment: Can you tell us why you want a second app within the first app? Seems like a pretty odd requirement, there may be a more obvious way to do what you're trying to do. Does he just want a certain URL to point to a different application?

Comment: Yeh, so he wants a microsite to be http://example.com/microsite (For example) and the main website http://example.com. Each being seperate rails apps.

Comment: Then you can host it on two different domains and point them to each other .

Comment: How can one achieve this?

Comment: You can configure the routes individually for both the applications

Comment: Read more on it here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14693542/show-one-application-on-2-site-with-different-front-ends-but-same-back-end-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, two Rails apps with one inside the other is not possible.

If all you want is a special page for the client, you need a view, controller, and route:

`$ rails g controller Pages second_page`

And then change your route (`config/routes.rb`) from `get 'pages/second_page’` to `get '/second_page’`.

After starting up your `rails s`, you can then go to `localhost:3000/second_page` and see your page.

If I’m completely misunderstanding what you’re trying to do, please describe your situation a bit more and I’d be happy to help.