# A single Rails app hosting multiple domains with caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, dns

I want to build a rails app that will host multiple domains(sites).
 Some content will be similar across all the sites which is why I want it in the one database/app. I thought that I could use a different controller for each domain/site with each action relating to a single page ( each site will only have 4-5 pages ).

This seems possible given the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207657/rails-routing-to-handle-multiple-domains-on-single-application/4737007#4737007), however I'd like to know what effects this would have on caching, using nginx as the server ( As it's mostly static content I'd like to use page caching )
i.e wouldn't the app need to hit at every request to process the right page/domain?

Answer (score 0):

I dont think thats a good solution. You should setup the application n times and handel the domains/subdomains using nginx and the `upstream` module.

Using one single instance of an application for various domains seems to be a loose solution to me. I would avoid that unless the content of the sites does depend on another directly. And even in that case I think an API is the better solution.