# Separate Domain for Namespaced Routes in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm working on a Rails 4 app. One part of the app is a customer portal that has to be accessed from a separate domain.

I have everything working fine by navigating to `domain.com/cp`. The routes use namespaced controllers:

```
namespace :cp do
    get :dashboard, to: 'dashboard#index', path: ''
    ...
end
```

How should I set up DNS records and change the routes definition so that another domain `cpdomain.com` points to `domain.com/cp` properly (no redirecting).

Thanks.

Comment: Which is the rails related problem?

Answer (score 4):

This answer can be useful for the rails routes problem:

[Rails routing to handle multiple domains on single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207657/rails-routing-to-handle-multiple-domains-on-single-application)

Shortened:

1) define a custom constraint class in lib/domain_constraint.rb:

```
class DomainConstraint
  def initialize(domain)
    @domains = [domain].flatten
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @domains.include? request.domain
  end
end
```

2) use the class in your routes with the new block syntax

```
constraints DomainConstraint.new('mydomain.com') do
  root :to => 'mydomain#index'
end

root :to => 'main#index'
```

or the old-fashioned option syntax

```
root :to => 'mydomain#index', :constraints => DomainConstraint.new('mydomain.com')
```