# Multiple Domain Routing App from rails 3 to 4 fails Invalid route name, already in use: 'root' (ArgumentError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes, multiple-domains

Have and old rails 3 app with a routes.rb like this

```
RailsAppli::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "landing#pos", :constraints => { :host => "pos.com.ar" }

  root :to => "landing#desa", :constraints => { :host => "desa.com.ar" }

  root :to => "landing#plan", :constraints => { :host => "dise.com.ar" }
```

thats work fine but i upgraded to rails 4 and

Invalid route name, already in use: 'root'  (ArgumentError)

Whats the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the domain of your app?

Answer (score 0):

Updating answer based on: [Separate Domain for Namespaced Routes in Rails 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122140/separate-domain-for-namespaced-routes-in-rails-4)

Shortened:

1) define a custom constraint class in lib/domain_constraint.rb:

```
class DomainConstraint
  def initialize(domain)
    @domains = [domain].flatten
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @domains.include? request.domain
  end
end
```

2) use the class in your routes with the new block syntax

```
constraints DomainConstraint.new('mydomain.com') do
  root :to => 'mydomain#index'
end

root :to => 'main#index'
```

or the old-fashioned option syntax

```
root :to => 'mydomain#index', :constraints => DomainConstraint.new('mydomain.com')
```

Comment: ok, thanks. but i need to rooting diferents domains to certain landing in my app. Like pos.com.ar to landing#pos. In rails 3 this routes.rb are good whats is the rails 4 way? thanks

Comment: Thanks but i need domains, are diferents domains and one app serves diferent landing pages for these domains.

Comment: okay see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24122140/separate-domain-for-namespaced-routes-in-rails-4

Answer (score -1):

Done!.

Only one root.

then

```
RailsAppli::Application.routes.draw do
    get '/', :to => "landing#pos", :constraints => { :host => "pos.com.ar" }

    get '/', :to => "landing#desa", :constraints => { :host => "desa.com.ar" }

    get '/', :to => "landing#plan", :constraints => { :host => "dise.com.ar" }
```

Thanks