# Different apps for website and control panel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications

I'm developing my first useful rails app at the moment and have a general question.

How are bigger applications like digitalocean.com or invisionapp.com set up:
Are the website and control panel always two different applications? 
If not, what is the setup to seperate these two in one app on different subdomains, for example with rails?

I hope the question is clear, I wasn't able two find an answer.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check you this question [Rails routing to handle multiple domains on single application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207657/rails-routing-to-handle-multiple-domains-on-single-application)

I'm not sure about digital ocean architecture, but I think that they have multiple apps.

At the beginning of learning rails it is not necessary to build website and control panel as different apps.

Let them be a single app, just locate them on different subdomains.
And with help of constrains in routes.rb you can route requests to different controllers, depending on required domain.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to have a look into that :)