# Detect the request domain from the routes.rb file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have several domains, say `foo.com` and `baz.com`, pointing to the same application.
For some of these domains I need to include the locale in the URL, and for other ones the locale should not be present in the URL.
For example, `foo.com/en/about` would be the same as `baz.com/about`.

What I thought of, is including something like `(:locale)` conditionally in the URL, based on the domain.

I wonder if it is possible to detect the domain of the request in the `routes.rb` file?
For example something like `request.domain` which is available from a controller, but from the `routes.rb` file.

Comment: Can you accept the answer if you found it helpful!

Comment: could you provide your route file?

Answer (score 1):

From the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737007/2018293. You can define a custom constraints class in `lib/domain_constraint.rb`;

```
class DomainConstraint
  def initialize(domain)
    @domains = [domain].flatten
  end

  def matches?(request)
    @domains.include? request.domain
  end
end
```

and then use this in your routes;

```
constraints DomainConstraint.new('mydomain.com') do
  root :to => 'mydomain#index'
  #other routes for the domain
end
```