# How to pass params to a block in Rails routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, ruby-on-rails-3

I am using Rails 3. And I'm wondering how to pass params to some blocks in `routes.rb`.

What I'm trying to do is to make a `catch all` route, that check from `slugs` database the model name of it by the id.

After getting the `model name` i pluralize it to get the controller name.

```
match '/:id', :controller => proc { Slug.find_by_iid(params[:id]).model.pluralize }, :action => :show
```

The table `slugs`

```
model    iid
-----    -----
post     4d2c7de0c5abe7f8a9000007
item     4d2c7de0c5abe7f809000004
```

When I try to access some pages like `/4d2c7de0c5abe7f8a9000007` I got this error:

```
Started GET "/4d2c7de0c5abe7f8a9000007" for
127.0.0.1 at 2011-01-12 00:04:31 +0200

ActionController::RoutingError (wrong constant name #<Proc:0x0000010337c310@):

Rendered /Users/amr/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3/gems/actionpack-3.0.3/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/routing_error.erb within rescues/layout (1.2ms)
```

**The expected is to point to posts#view with iid: 4d2c7de0c5abe7f8a9000007**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`proc` returns a Proc, but `match` is expecting a string. You could try adding `.call` to have the proc return its value. Though I'm not sure if this will end up calling the proc each time or only when `routes` is loaded...

**EDIT**

Seems I was way off-base with my earlier response and comments. Maybe something like this?:

```
match '/:id', :to => proc { |env|
  id = env["action_dispatch.request.path_parameters"][:id]
  model = Slug.find_by_iid(id).model
  controller = [model.pluralize.camelize,"Controller"].join.constantize
  controller.action("show").call(env)
}
```

Though this really ought to be defined in a library and included. Perhaps someone knows a better way?

Comment: I could remove `proc` like this `:controller => Slug.find_by_iid(params[:id]).model.pluralize` but still the problem is how to get `params[:id]` value. When i try to run the app it throws me an error `../config/routes.rb:6:in `block in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `params' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x000001031a2af8> (NameError)`

Comment: when i made it `controller => proc { Slug.find_by_iid(params[:id]).model.pluralize }.call` it threw me `/config/routes.rb:6:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>': undefined local variable or method `params' for #<ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper:0x000001030c9b40> (NameError)` ALSO!

Comment: Ahh, I missed the `params` in there. I don't think that works -- `params` is set in the controller, not the routing engine. Take a look at the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596312/dynamic-url-controller-mapping-for-routes-in-rails

Comment: Thanks. I already read it before, not the solution that am looking for!

Comment: Evolution of this solution.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5641786/testing-rack-routing-using-rspec

Answer (score 0):

Putting this in your routes seems really hacky. I would recommend creating a Slugs controller, passing this task onto that, and redirecting to the appropriate controller from there. Assuming your other pages use standard RESTful routes, you could do something like this:

Change route to this:

```
match '/:id', :controller => :slugs, :action => :show
```

Slugs controller:

```
def show
  slug = Slug.find_by_iid(params[:id])

  redirect_to send("#{slug.model}_url", params[:id])
end
```

Comment: I dont want to make redirect dude! I just want to make the application understand my slug, and load the related model. like in facebook.com and quora.com