# Rails routes with clean urls

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My problem is i want to remove the querystring part of this URL and make it clean.

```
http://staging.mysite.com/mycontroller?name=/philippines/about-manila
```

currently i have `MyController.index()` and I parse the name parameter in this method.

What i would eventually want is this :

```
http://staging.mysite.com/mycontroller/philippines/about-manila
```

the parameter part `'philippines/about-manila'` can have arbitrary number of parameters, like

```
http://staging.mysite.com/mycontroller/philippines/about-manila/people
```

How can i do this in routes?

Comment: are you using rails2.x or rails3.x?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690298/how-do-we-identify-parameters-in-a-dynamic-url/4705154#4705154

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you want [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#route-globbing).  If you use:

```
map.my_route '/mycontroller/*parts',
             :controller => :mycontroller,
             :action => :index
```

and then go to the URL http://staging.mysite.com/mycontroller/philippines/about-manila/people, then your `mycontroller` controller's `index` action will be called, and `params[:parts]` will contain the array `["philippines", "about-manila", "people"]`.

Answer (score 2):

Is it really arbitrary — or just variable?

If it's just variable, you can enclose optional parameters in parentheses:

```
match '/:city(/:section(/:subsection))', :controller => :mycontroller,
    :action => :index
```

For Rails 2.x:

```
map.connect '/:city(/:section(/:subsection))', :controller => :mycontroller,
    :action => :index
```

Comment: is this just limited to 3 url segments ?

Answer (score 1):

For Rails 2.x you can use

```
map.my_route '/:my_param', :controller => :mycontroller, :action => :index
```

Then in your controller you can access

```
params[:my_param]
```

If you want links just go with

```
my_route_path(:my_param => "mytekst")
```